# Change HTML markup used it PopupTemplate in ArcGIS (javascript api)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

everyone. I'm sorry if it is common question but I'd googled it for a couple days and still haven't find the answer. Everything I see in documentation is style an exist HTML layout, which looks like:

```html
<div class="esriPopupWrapper" style="position: absolute;">
<div class="sizer">
    <div class="titlePane" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
        <div class="spinner hidden" title="Searching..."></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="titleButton prev hidden" title="Prev"></div>
        <div class="titleButton next hidden" title="Next"></div>
        <div class="titleButton maximize" title="Maximize"></div>
        <div class="titleButton close" title="Close"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sizer content">
    <div class="contentPane"></div>
</div>
<div class="sizer">
    <div class="actionsPane">
        <div class="actionList hidden">
            <a title="Zoom" class="action zoomTo" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Zoom to</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pointer hidden"></div>
```

But I need to setup totally different popup, put style on it and, surely, link it to data. I see there's the PopupTemplate class that allow to put data in 'content' block or 'title' block, but how to define own sections, change markup and do stuff like this?

What I tried:

- delete sections in popup.domNode and then add my ones - data stoped
  synchronize.
- changed markup directly in popup.domNode.innerHTML - same thing
- thought that it is crucial to update ._title and ._content properties to show where's now these blocks placed, but have same result.

Comment: its still not clear to me what you can't accomplish by passing your own HTML to setContent() or setTitle()

Comment: Content that you're setting by `setContent()` method is placed inside `<div class="contentPane"></div>` but I need completely different markup for the tooltip.

Comment: @JohnGravois setTitle() and setContent() only cover two of the three areas.  There is no setActions().  So that's one thing you can't accomplish (as far as I can tell).